# open directory from result of previous command - windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

There is a command in node.js that outputs the directory of installed modules:

```
 npm root
 prints: C:\Users\Admin\node_modules
```

How do I open windows explorer to this path? Can it be done in one line?

something like

```
explorer npm root (doesnt work of course)
```

Comment: In cmd you could use `doskey *explorer=for /f "usebackq delims=" %c in (\`$*\`) do @"%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe" "%c"`. Then for example run `*explorer npm root`. I added the initial "*" to distinguish the name, while keeping it easy to remember. doskey macros are evaluated in the console server, conhost.exe, so the start of the raw input has to be a case-insensitive match to `*explorer`. The server rewrites the command line as `for /f "usebackq delims=" %c in (\`npm root\`) do @"%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe" "%c"`, which is what cmd reads from stdin.

Comment: thanks, that is def answer-worthy, feel free to post it.. Is there any way to make *explorer global and persistent? That is, prevent having to run the first command each time.